# Strange "inFeatures" value for Intersect tool

Tags: arcpy, intersect

I am rather new to Python but I am trying to define a function that will take the output of one of my prior functions (5 buffered stream files) and intersect each unique streamBuffer file with an LULC shapefile. So, I want to create 5 unique intersection shapefiles.

My problem comes when trying to figure out how to input this into a variable that will fit inside the arcpy Intersection_analysis tool.

My code currently looks like this:

```
    def identHabitat(self):
         '''Creates a polygon shapefile by intersecting the shapefiles 
         resulting from calcBuffer, identCover, and identDev. The result 
         shows areas within a specific watershed where habitat suitable for 
         the desired species could be found.'''
         workspace = arcpy.env.workspace = (sys.argv[7])
         arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
         buffList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*buff_{0}*".format(self.abbrv))
         unionFile = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*{0}_LULC*".format(self.abbrv))
         inFeatures = [unionFile]
         for fc in buffList:
              outFeatures = "{0}_Habitat".format(self.abbrv)
              inFeatures.extend(fc)
              try:
                  intLayers = arcpy.Intersect_analysis(inFeatures, outFeatures)
                  message = "Habitat successfully identified!"
              except:
                  message = "Habitat could not be identified, please try again."
         return message
```

I put a breakpoint on the line defining the workspace and watched the "inFeatures" variable. This was its value:

[image]

Obviously, this is not what I'm trying to do. I want my variable to have a value of: [[u'nopa_LULC.shp'], fc]

And again, I'm new to Python so I'm sure some of this is not the best coding you've ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

`inFeatures.extend (fc)` adds a string to the list `outFeatures`. `fc` is a string, and `.extend` iterates the string and adds each character to the list `unionFile`. `unionFile` itself is a list of a list, since `unionFile = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*{0}_LULC*".format(self.abbrv))` creates a list, and then `inFeatures = [unionFile]` creates a list of that list.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
workspace = arcpy.env.workspace = (sys.argv[7])
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
buffList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*buff_{0}*".format(self.abbrv))
unionFile = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*{0}_LULC*".format(self.abbrv)) [0] #get first item in list??
# inFeatures = [unionFile] #not needed
for fc in buffList:
  outFeatures = "{0}_Habitat".format(self.abbrv)
  #inFeatures.extend(fc) #also not needed
  try:
      intLayers = arcpy.Intersect_analysis([fc, unionFile], outFeatures) #first input of intersect is a list of all feature classes to intersect
      message = "Habitat successfully identified!"
  except:
      message = "Habitat could not be identified, please try again."
```